# D'Fusion AR SDK for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Anyone happens to know where to download D'Fusion's plugion for Unity3D?

I know they once supported it but I simply can't find it on their webpage, also asked around on their forums and got no replies. It all points to no longer be a supported platform but they still have a Unity3D forum open, despite having little to no feedback.

Comment: It seems they remove the download site while ago and the support at forum looks really abandoned. I will suggest not picking dfusion and move to more active and powerful sdks.

Comment: I tried to search for this as well but I found basically nothing.